# Sublime Text: disable refresh/replacement in 'Replace' function?

Tags: sublimetext, replaceall, sublimetext4

using the "Replace..." [Find menu] function a slide-in at the bottom appears with an option field/entry for "Find:" and below that one, one for "Replace:"

having completed a replace [eg "Find: abc", "Replace: xyz"] for instance by employing "Replace All" the very slide-in disappears

now for another, new, search, for instance within a document having selected a different, let's say word like "oha", that selection 'oha' is auto-copied over as new entry in "Find:" when using "Replace..." again. this is to say that now in "Find:" the entry does read "oha" tho didn't paste it manually in -- the "abc" entry fromthe previous search got replaced

however, the last entry in the "Replace:"-entry-field remains unchanged

it's the "Find:" entry that get's auto filled in w/out the option [as far as i could figure out]

and that exactly is my question about :
any option to modify Sublime's settings such that nothing gets changed/auto-copied/filled-in at "Find:" ?

pretty annoying behaviour, as i experience it, for instance when having to replace just a single character combi within similar text and each time the copy-selected text get's auto-copied/filled-in at "Find:" rather than leave it be till the usr opts to modify that entry from previous replace-calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Find` and `Find and Replace` widgets automatically populate the Find box with either the current selection if there is one, or the previous value used in that box. This box is a dropdown, which contains the previous values used, so you can easily go back through your history in that window and not have to re-type a complicated regular expression, for example.

When the Find box opens pre-populated with a value, it is automatically selected, so to get rid of it all you have to do is hit <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Alternatively, you can just begin typing your new search query, and it will erase the old one.

There is a setting in Sublime Text 4 that modifies this behavior:

```json
// If true, the selected text will be copied into the find panel when it's
// shown.
// On Mac, this value is overridden in the platform specific settings.
"find_selected_text": true,
```

If you set `"find_selected_text": false,` in your user settings, you can disable this behavior.

Comment: thanks, **MattDMo** ! works exactly as advertized. this solves my problem and answers the question.